# Will this query return ALL files modified today?

Tags: 2010, sql-query

I'm running SharePoint 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

It's hugely important that I create a list of every file within a given content database that has been modified today, 10/31.  Will this query do it or will it leave anything -anything at all- out?

```
SELECT [DirName], 
       [LeafeName], 
       [TimeLastModified] 
FROM   [WSS_Content_TARGETDB].[dbo].[AllDocs] 
WHERE  [TimeLastModified] BETWEEN '20121031' AND '20121101';
```

I'm crossing my fingers that this will list everything without any gaps.

Answer (score 2):

NEVER READ DIRECTLY FROM THE DATABASES
(unless there is no other option)

This will probably work with the current patches it might, but it's not documented or guaranteed and even thought it might work now it might stop working if a patch is applied.

Have you consider using the change log which is meant exactly for getting things like this?
See [Using the Change Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447511.aspx)

Comment: This isn't meant to be an ongoing solution for something, I just need to create a comprehensive list of files that were modified on 10/31/2012.  I'll use any method that will give me a complete list.

Comment: If you have configured the Usage and Health Data collection in Central Administration Web site, you can use the Web Analytics reports to get the insight you are looking for, plus more.

Comment: @HosseinAarabi - Can you go into greater detail on that, please?

Comment: I will point you to two blogs where they show you how to configure this service: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/05/03/web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010-insights-into-reports-and-metrics.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70865/SharePoint-2010-Logging-Database

Comment: Also, the Usage database is the only SharePoint database that is OK for you to read against. As Per Jakobsen mentioned, you should never directly access or modify any other SP database.

Comment: @HosseinAarabi - Okay, I've been poking around in the views under WSS_Logging but I'm having trouble finding the information I want.  Which view would contain records of file modifications?